# make a application that render with Direct 2D and using less CPU and GPU power

Tags: c++, direct2d

i'm new to direct 2D. I want to make a simple application using direct 2D.
Until now made a application where i call natives in loop to draw shapes, texts and images, depending on what user does (eg: when mouse is over a button, its rect become darker). This application using around 16% CPU and 20% GPU while running.

I'm thinking to re-code my application so it will call the natives once only if need change something. However for this i need to syncronize somehow the rendering loop to screen refresh rate i think. Is that correct?

Does anyone know how can i do that? Maybe there is a better idea to render with direct 2D using less CPU & GPU?

i know i can easily make a windows form with c++ CLR and .NET, but i want make it with direct 2D only.

EDIT 1:
Also if i add a animated image i render its frames in loop and then need redraw everything. Is there any better way to redraw only the image?
I read about D2D layers, is it good idea to create a new layer when i want render a animated image or no?

Comment: You don't need to constantly redraw your view. You only need to do it when something in it changes, e.g. the mouse moves over a UI element that needs to change appearance, a timer goes off to update an animation, or Windows passes a WM_PAINT message.

Comment: Direct2D is the right approach for intensive drawing. Just google for the documentation. Start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/overview-of-the-windows-graphics-architecture).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yes that i want to do, but the problem here is how windows will know when something need to change? I made my own buttons classes so windows can't know when i have the mouse over a button and when leave that area

Comment: You'll need to track the mouse movement, detect when you need to change the appearence of something, then either invalidate or redraw part or all of the screen when something on it changes.

Comment: Instead of using loops (usually badly coded in samples you find on internet), you can *compose* your scene using Windows Composition that hosts the swapchain and handles all present/sync stuff for you. Google for Kenny Kerr's 2014 articles on Windows/Direct Composition. This is the seminal sample: https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/62923cdacaba28fedc4f3dab6e0c12ec . You'll need Direct2D, the two can be combined. Check samples here : https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples you'll still have to detect changes and modify the compositon tree accordingly but no more loops

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i did that already. The button class i made it check in loop if mouse is inside the rect of this button and it change its color. But these checks need run in loop again and if NOT call Sleep() in that loop for a few milliseconds it still use a lot CPU. So every how many milliseconds need to check for mouse position?